# How to implement language Interoperability in Hazelcast

Tags: java, c#, caching, hazelcast

I wish to have my distributed Cache available to applications available in different languages (say C#,Java).
I am populating my Cache via Java API as follows

```
IMap.put(1,new Person(“anonymous”));
```

Now this Person is a Java Class. If this cache needs to be accessed and used by C# client, I guess it will not be able to do that unless the Class is somehow language independent.(C# knows how to make a C# specific Object)

I read on Hazelcast documentation regarding Portable Serialization and it seems there is a provision to do that.
http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.5/manual/html/portableserialization.html

My Person class now implements Portable interface and implements all the methods defined in Portable Interface.
My question is how does C# Client access this cache?
Will there be a need of a POJO in C# also which implements Portable interface?

1. Does implementing Portable interface by a C# POJO suffice?
2. Do I need anything else so that my client written in different language works?
3. Also if say my Java Person class gets Modified (a new property is added. Will this also need a change in my C# POJO).I read something about portable version. Can I use this version to make sure that change in Java POJO does not affect C# client?

Comment: Hi Ankarlu, I have answered this question on the Hazelcast mailinglist.